# database and package location of Android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing Android application. I use SQLite to store data in user's device. The problem is I don't know where the database is. I also can't locate the package of my application in the device. Usually package can be found at directory **Android/Data/com.example.xxx**. Can anybody tell me why?

By the way I follow SQLite tutorial from http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/use-of-sqlite/

I have checked the code and it doesn't show where the database saved.

Comment: provide some code! maybe /data/data/com.xxx/databases/ is a place that you should look for it

Answer (score 0):

> I use SQLite to store data in user's device. The problem is I don't know where the database is. I also can't locate the package of my application in the device.

You do not have access to internal storage on a production device.

> Usually package can be found at directory Android/Data/com.example.xxx

I have never seen such a directory.

A SQLite database traditionally, on Android 4.1 and below, would be in `/data/data/com.example.xxx/databases/`. However, you can only get to that directory on the emulator and on rooted devices. And, on Android 4.2 and higher, the path to internal storage depends on the user account.

Your application can use `getDatabasePath()` to learn where your database is stored (e.g., for logging), and you can copy that file from within your app to external storage (e.g., via a Backup action bar item).